# Get entity by int Id in GAE in GO

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get entity Key by its int Id. (not the entity itself, but it's Key) (in the long run I do it to find entities parent)

```
Data from DatastoreViewer:

Entity Kind
File
Entity Key
ag9kZXZ-dHJhc2hib3hhcHByIgsSBEZpbGUYgICAgICAwAoMCxIERmlsZRiAgICAgIDACww
ID
6473924464345088
Parent
ag9kZXZ-dHJhc2hib3hhcHByEQsSBEZpbGUYgICAgICAwAoM
File: id=5910974510923776
```

I do it like this:

```
k := datastore.NewKey(c, "File", "", 6473924464345088, nil)
currentDirQuery := datastore.NewQuery("File").Filter("__key__ =", k).KeysOnly()
keys, err := currentDirQuery.GetAll(c, nil)
```

The length if keys is 0. What do I do wrong?

Comment: the Parent Key is part of the Entity Key. If you only specify the entity key that is a completely different key and that is why is returning zero elements. If you don't have the parent key then your model is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the key already why are doing a keys only query matching the key ?  Why don't you just do a datastore.Get() with the key?

As to why your keys_only query is not working, you are not including the ancestor in the key you are constructing , the key in your example has a parent you showed `ag9kZXZ-dHJhc2hib3hhcHByEQsSBEZpbGUYgICAgICAwAoM` this urlsafe version of the key must have a parent if you are specifying an ancestor.

Using python we can decode this key

```
> ndb.Key(urlsafe="ag9kZXZ-dHJhc2hib3hhcHByIgsSBEZpbGUYgICAgICAwAoMCxIERmlsZRiAgICAgIDACww")
Key('File', 5910974510923776, 'File', 6473924464345088, app='dev~trashboxapp')
```

See the parent Key is  `Key('File', 5910974510923776)`

You can not perform a partial match on a child with the key you created for the query. You can only perform ancestor queries which will return the ancestor and all of it's children irrespective of the depth of the heirarchy.

This also means a datastore.Get() will fail with the key you have created in your example code.

So construct you key so that it includes the ancestor - see the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Retrieving_an_entity

But to be honest what you are doing is completely redundant unless it's just an excercise in understanding whats going on and your trying to roundtrip a key -> query -> key

Comment: You would be surprised, but I do not specify ancestor and try to get key because I want to find Parent of this entity. So I want to get the key and retrieve Parent from it.
Possibly you know the other way to find a parent of custom entity.

Comment: Well you certainly can not do it the way you are attempting. In your example you already have the parent.  So I am not sure why you are trying to find it that way.  About the only thing you can do is store the id, in another property and query based on that property.

Comment: As far as I can see I do not have the parent. Where do you see it? 6473924464345088 in my code is int id of the child, not parent. And I'm trying to find the parent by that child id.

Comment: Yes you do, it's in the key string you show.

`s~fish-and-lily> ndb.Key(urlsafe="ag9kZXZ-dHJhc2hib3hhcHByIgsSBEZpbGUYgICAgICAwAoMCxIERmlsZRiAgICAgIDACww")
Key('File', 5910974510923776, 'File', 6473924464345088, app='dev~trashboxapp')
`  - See the structure of the key.  You should read some docs.

Comment: You can not search for a parent with only the child's id as I have already explained. The parent is in the key

Comment: I have added a bit more detail to the answer.

Comment: You also printed out the parent key in your output, so you have shown you have the parent.